# R package listed on CRAN but not in available package

Tags: r, cran

I want to install a package that is listed in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html as available in CRAN, but when I check in R the install packages menu or the available.packages() command, I can't see the package there.

Do I need to do something different to install those packages? Why aren't those packages available?

The packages I'm interested on are WikipediR ( https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WikipediR/index.html ), WikidataR and WikipediaR.

If it matters, I'm using R 2.15.0 in Windows XP.

Comment: is there some reason you can't update r?

Comment: Thank you all. Updating R worked.

Comment: The reason to not having updated R previously was just a matter of trying not to break anything that is still working in my old laptop. In fact, after updating it has been complicated to make R-commander work again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation for `?available.packages`...

> By default, the return value includes only packages whose version and
>   OS requirements are met by the running version of R, and only gives
>   information on the latest versions of packages.

In other words... your R 2.15 is likely too old for the package you are looking to download.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download the package source manually add the package to the package library usually found somewhere like "win-library/2.15/" but like Cory mentioned it is likely that the older version of R does not support the package build.

Answer (score 0):

The advice given so far is a bit incomplete although I do agree you need to update your R version if you want to use these packages. Looks like they don't need compilation so you might have been able to either install from a local copy or drop R code in, but critically they depend on `httr` which requires R 3.0.0 or above. They were released only relatively recently, so there will be no Windows binaries from back in 2012. (Your copy of R is from 30-Mar-2012.)  Look in the DESCRIPTION file which is presented in a nice web format at the CRAN/package listing:

```
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WikidataR/index.html
    Imports:    httr, jsonlite, WikipediR
   Suggests:    testthat, knitr, pageviews

# only one version of these two
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/WikidataR/WikidataR_1.0.0.tar.gz
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/WikipediaR/WikipediaR_1.0.tar.gz
# pick one of these
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/WikipediR/
```